# scons invocation error building AllJoyn for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, scons, alljoyn

I'm trying to build AllJoyn for IOS using Xcode (5.1.1) on OSX Mavericks (10.9.3). I have followed all the steps posted [here](https://allseenalliance.org/docs-and-downloads/documentation/configuring-build-environment-ios-and-osx) to the letter but keep getting a "Shell script invocation error", error: can't exec 'scons' (No such file or directory) on the last step in the instructions and cannot figure out how to resolve it, I have installed scons with homebrew and tried donloading and installing it manually but for some reason it can't find it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It can't find scons, make sure that it's in your path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution. Brady's comment was right, Xcode could not find `scons`.

In order to fix it, I changed the field for "Build Tool" under Target -> info, it originally had only "scons" as its value so I did a search for it in a terminal (`which scons`), and put the full path in the setting (in my case "/usr/local/bin/scons").

In addition to this issue, I had an issue with openssl not being found even after executing the command `launchctl setenv OPENSSL_ROOT <path to top level folder of openssl>` so under Build Settings I added a user-defined setting with the key "OPENSSL_ROOT" with the value of the full path to the openssl top level folder.

[image: screenshot of Build Settings with OPENSSL_ROOT key]

Comment: Thanks Drew! That was very helpful! I was kind of wonderstruck at this issue.

Comment: after changing buildTool path mine is still saying .
error: can't exec 'scons' (No such file or directory).

Comment: and also can you tell what this directory field does should i put path there too?

Comment: sorry I was doing change in wrong scheme.
now I m getting this error.any help?
"Command /usr/local/bin/scons failed with exit code 2"